# How to extract number values from an array and then combine it with another string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $qwe2 from which I need to make 2 separate arrays. One which will contain not numeric values in this example mom, sister and an array with numeric values 11dad 13brother.

```
$qwe = " mom   11dad  sister  13brother ";
$qwe0 = ucwords(strtolower($qwe));
$qwe1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$qwe);
$qwe7 = trim($qwe1);
$qwe2 = explode(' ',$qwe7);

var_dump($qwe2);
```

This is what it looks like :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'mom' (length=3)
  1 => string '11dad' (length=5)
  2 => string 'sister' (length=6)
  3 => string '13brother' (length=9)
```

All these things above are also needed but I managed to do them easily. I don't understand the part below.

Desired result : `$asd = array("mom, sister");` and `$zxc = array("11dad, 13brother");`

Also I have a string `$doyou = "Do you like ?"` which I need to combine with the new array `$asd` which will result in : `Do you like mom?, Do you like sister?`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the rules for choosing "mom" and "sister" to be in the first array? and the other values to be in the second array?

Comment: I tried array_slice and I tried to access every element of array by position, but that didn't work so well. So I one array I need numeric values (11dad,13 brother) and in second array not numeric (mom, sister)

Comment: We understand what you need; but you need to show some effort to solve your own problem, not just ask people to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PHP's `array_filter()` with some custom functions that check for numbers in the string:

```
$asd = array_filter($qwe2, 'hasNumbers');
$zxc = array_filter($qwe2, 'hasNoNumbers');

function hasNumbers($string)
{
    return strcspn($string, '0123456789') != strlen($string);
}
function hasNoNumbers($string)
{
    return strcspn($string, '0123456789') == strlen($string);
}
```

Then `array_map()` can help you do the string replace:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map('myStringReplace', $asd));

function myStringReplace($string)
{
    return str_replace('?', $string, 'Do you like ?');
}
```

Comment: This works. I only need to figure how to implode $doyou and $asd. Thanks.

Comment: @Kotidrmakavez I just added a solution for that. Sorry, missed it the first time around.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks again!